# Visual Studio - how to display exit code in output window without access to `main`

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, exit-code, boost-test

How do I get Visual Studio 2013 to display the exit code in the Output window when a program completes if I don't have access to `main`?

I'm using Boost test to run some tests. `main` is defined by the framework so I cannot simply print the exit code to stdout prior to completion. When all tests pass, the exit code is 0 otherwise it is generally 200 or 201.

When I run the tests in Xcode on OS X the value of the exit code is displayed in the console automatically. I'd like Visual Studio to do the same if possible.

Comment: It already does this.  You just have to configure the debugger correctly.  Project + Properties, Debugging, set the Command setting to the boost test runner.  Press F5 to run the test.

Comment: In Visual Studio, thread and process exit codes are automatically printed into the Output window, just select "Show output from: **Debug**".

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in built-in settings for Visual Studio that will do this directly.

However, you could define an alternate entry point for your application using the `/ENTRY` linker setting (`Property Pages->Linker->Advanced->Entry Point`). Making your own main function, you could call the main function from the test library, and print out its return code in your function. You would then have the option of returning its return code from your main function (or some other code of your choosing).

Comment: Thanks for the comment but Boost test already provides the option to supply your own main function but it's not the default. I was wondering if I could avoid the need to do that.